# Apollo Client and filtered queries

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm making an app for birdwatchers. When birdwatches see a bird, they record a `sighting`. I have a query for a feed of all birdwatchers sightings:

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_SIGHTINGS = gql`
  query Sightings($first: Int, $after: String) {
    sightings(first: $first, after: $after) {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
      }
    edges {
      node {
        id
        location
        note
        seenAt
        mapImage
        images {
          id
          url
        }
        user {
          id
          name
          emoji
        }
        bird {
          id
          commonName
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

and this works great. Now i want to have a seperate feed for an individual birdwatchers sightings. (this query is working fine on the server):

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const MY_SIGHTINGS = gql`
  query MySightings($first: Int, $after: String, $userId: ID) {
    mySightings: sightings(first: $first, after: $after, userId: $userId) @connection(key: "sightings", filter: ["userId"]) {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
      }
      edges {
        node {
          id
          location
          note
          seenAt
          mapImage
          images {
            id
            url
          }
          user {
            id
            name
            emoji
          }
          bird {
            id
            commonName
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

This works fine the first time the filtered query was run, however once the main feed component is rendered, the individual feed is now full of everyones sightings. How do I get the cache to descriminate between the two queries? The `@connection` directive sounded like it would be the trick but apparently not

Comment: user filtering should be implemented on server - filter when `userID` provided ... apollo already [should] keeps both results under separated keys (query+args) ... rendering code/usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the [Relay Specification](https://relay.dev/docs/en/graphql-server-specification.html) for my API which means that my 'collections' are objects rather than arrays. This means I need to set a specific Type Policy to get pagination to work. This also unfortunately also breaks Apollos automatic handling of query params. Turns out I need to add `userId` to the keyargs section of my type policy:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        sightings: {
          keyArgs: ["userId"],          
          merge(existing, incoming, { args }) {
            if (args && !args.after) {
              return incoming;
            }
            if (!existing) {
              return incoming;
            }
            const edges = unionBy("node.__ref", existing.edges, incoming.edges);
            return { ...incoming, edges };
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```